# Destroying specific terraform infrastructure

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I created infrastructure for different environment (testing / prod) with terraform using workspaces, locals and -backend-config so there is only two differents files, others files are common for both environment.

Unfortunately, I don't find a way to destroy specific environment the same way (without creating lots of specific files for each environment).

Am I missing something ? Is there a way do that ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance !

Regards,

Florent

EDIT : Thanks for answers, I managed to do what I wanted to do using workspaces, locals and backend-config !

Answer (score 9):

You can use `-target` to target specific resources to destroy.

```
terraform destroy \
  -target 'module.default.aws_autoscaling_group.one' \
  -target 'module.default.aws_autoscaling_group.two'
```

Notes

- quotations are required around the targets if using `count` or `for_each` logic which results in square brackets in the target names.
- single quotations are better since a `for_each` would return a double quoted key which would need to be escaped if surrounding the target with double quotes

Comment: Addition, to list the modules, run `$ terraform state list` more here https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/state/list.

Answer (score 1):

Using Terraform V 0.13

I have tried to pass `tfvars` file to destroy command like this:

```
terraform destroy -auto-approve -var-file="env/stage.tfvars"
```

Comment: These options are undocumented, the terraform apply -help command says nothing about using -var-file. And of course terraform destroy -help says it's an alias for apply -destroy. But this answer really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix terraform commands `init/workspace` to `plan/apply/destroy`.

so I guess you run with below commands to set the backend (where the tfstate files are saved)

```
terraform init -backend-config=<path>
terraform get
terraform workspace select <env>
```

Then you should run below commands with same `-var-file=<file>` or `-var 'foo=bar'` option for all plan, apply and destroy commands.

```
terraform plan -var-file=dev/terraformtfvars -var 'foo=bar'
terraform apply -var-file=dev/terraformtfvars -var 'foo=bar'
terraform destroy -var-file=dev/terraformtfvars -var 'foo=bar'
```

Let me know if this explains your concerns or not.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I'm not sure to understand why I should not mix init/workspace and plan/apply/destroy, can you explain it a little bit more ? At this moment, i'm using locals inside my .tf files so if I correctly understand what you're saying I should create separated file for variables and tell terraform to use it with -var-file argument ? I'm pretty new using terraform, sorry if some questions look stupid to you ! Thanks you :)

Comment: I adjust the answer, that you can manage the environment with `-var-file=dev/terraformtfvars` or `-var-file=prod/terraformtfvars`